# Counting distinct stores SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am fairly new to SQL and was wondering if anyone could help with my code.

I am trying to count the distinct number of stores that are tied to a certain Warehouse which is tied to a purchase order.

Example: If there are 100 stores with this PO that came from Warehouse #2 or #5 or etc... then I would like:

```
               | COUNT_STORE | WH_LOCATION |
             1 |     100     |     2       |
             2 |     25      |     5       |
             3 |     56      |     1       |
```

[]
My Code:

```
select count(distinct Store_ID) as Count_Store, WH_Location
from alc_Loc
where alloc_PO = 11345
group by Store_ID, WH_Location
```

When I run this I get a 1 for "count_store" and it shows me the WH_Location multiple times. I feel as if something is not tying in correctly.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the selected columns that are not arguments to a set function! In this case do `group by WH_Location`.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `store_id` from the `group by`:

```
select count(distinct Store_ID) as Count_Store, WH_Location
from alc_Loc
where alloc_PO = 11345
group by WH_Location;
```

When you include `Store_ID` in the `group by`, you are getting a separate row for each `Store_ID`.  The distinct count is then obviously 1 (or 0 if the store id is `NULL`).